# Hadoop 2.4 Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7

Tags: hadoop, maven-3

I am trying to install Hadoop 2.4.0 from source, I got the following error, I have googled around but cannot find any solution.

Please help.

Regards

O/S Ubuntu: 12.04 (64-bit) 
Java: java version "1.6.0_45" 
protoc —version: libprotoc 2.5.0

Command: `mvn package -Pdist,native -DskipTests -Dtar -X`

Error message:

```
    [INFO] Total time: 18.096s
    [INFO] Finished at: Mon Apr 28 18:56:00 HKT 2014
    [INFO] Final Memory: 59M/1303M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------    
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (make) on project hadoop-common: An Ant BuildException has occured: exec returned: 1
    [ERROR] around Ant part ...<exec dir="/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.4.0-src/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/target/native" executable="cmake" failonerror="true">... @ 4:138 in /usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.4.0-src/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/target/antrun/build-main.xml
    [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (make) on project hadoop-common: An Ant BuildException has occured: exec returned: 1
around Ant part ...<exec dir="/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.4.0-src/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/target/native" executable="cmake" failonerror="true">... @ 4:138 in /usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.4.0-src/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/target/antrun/build-main.xml
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:317)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:152)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:555)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: An Ant BuildException has occured: exec returned: 1
around Ant part ...<exec dir="/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.4.0-src/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/target/native" executable="cmake" failonerror="true">... @ 4:138 in /usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.4.0-src/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/target/antrun/build-main.xml
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.antrun.AntRunMojo.execute(AntRunMojo.java:355)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: /usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.4.0-src/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/target/antrun/build-main.xml:4: exec returned: 1
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExecute(ExecTask.java:646)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExec(ExecTask.java:672)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.execute(ExecTask.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor20.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.antrun.AntRunMojo.execute(AntRunMojo.java:327)
    ... 21 more
```

Answer (score 9):

sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev

sudo apt-get install libssl-dev

---

You need the support of the two libraries

Comment: I would like to know how to install those two libs in Mac OS?

Comment: For yum: sudo yum install openssl-devel zlib-devel

Comment: @JiacaiLiu you probably don't care anymore, but for posterity it looks like the Xcode command line tools contain `zlib1g-dev`, and `openssl` (`brew install openssl`) contains `libssl-dev`. You'll need to force linking of `openssl`: `brew link openssl --force`.

Answer (score 0):

Go to hadoop-common > target > native > CMakeFiles, check the error log CMakeError.log.

Is g++ installed?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:
sudo apt-get install ant.
It worked for me.